# Where is 'resources' in SurfaceView defined and how can I access it from different class?

Tags: android, kotlin, sprite

I am trying to program an app with sprites. Right now I am passing an image to each sprite object. But since the image is the same for every sprite, I would rather store the image as a class property.
Unfortunately the variable 'resources' is only accessible in the SurfaceView class and not in the sprite class.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log.d
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.SurfaceView
import android.view.View
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class GameView(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet): SurfaceView(context, attributes), SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder?) {
    Note(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.note), 200)
    }
}
```

The code of Note:

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.util.Log.d

class Note (var image: Bitmap, var x: Int) {
    var y: Int = 0
    var width: Int = 0
    var height: Int = 0
    private var vx = -10
    private val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    private val screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels - 100
    // I would like to load the image like this:
    private val image2: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.note)

    init {
    width = image.width
    height = image.height
    //x = screenWidth/2
    y = ((screenHeight-height)/2).toInt()

    }

    fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), null)
    }

    fun update(){
    x += vx
    if (x < 0) {
        x = screenWidth
    }
    }

}
```

I tried to use GameView.resources and SurfaceView.resources, but neither works.
Where does the resources variable come from and how can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources) is a class for accessing an application's resources. You can get instance of this class from

- An instance of Context class or its sub classes, like Application, Activity, Service, etc.
- An instance of View class or its sub classes like TextView, Button, SurfaceView, etc.

In your case, you can pass the context instance of GameView class (sub class of View class) when create a Node instance.

```
class GameView(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet): SurfaceView(context, attributes), SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder?) {
        // Pass context that associated with this view to Node constructor.
        Note(context, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.note), 200)
    }
}
```

then use it in Node class

```
// Modify Node constructor to add a Context parameter.
class Note (val context: Context, var image: Bitmap, var x: Int) {
    ...
    // Get resources instance from a Context instance.
    private val image2: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.note)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the Android [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources.html) object.  You can access it via [Context.resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) from any `Context` subclass, such as your `Activity`.  Note that you'll need a specific instance of a `Context` or `Activity` - just writing `Activity.resources` won't work.